# can not install ubuntu with 'resource busy' error

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my Dell G3 15 3579. Before I have SSD M.2 with Windows 10. I buy additional Samsung PRO EVO 860 and try to install ubuntu on it. During ubuntu installation I remove M.2 SSD from laptop.

Try a lot of times to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but every time system just "freeze" on restart state

Now I try to install Ubuntu 18.10, but I get following screen on restart state
[image]

I didn't make any changes to BIOS. Boot order I didn't change as well

**EDIT**:
during ubuntu 18.04 installation I setup following partition

1. / + /boot + /swap + EFI System Partition
2. / + EFI system partition

during ubuntu 18.10 installation I try to setup following partition

1. / + EFI ssytem partition
2. In final installation I just use "erase disk" + "use LVM with new ubuntu installation"

Answer (score 0):

Well... Looks like Dell G3 15 3579 and Ubuntu 18.* is not compatible

Dell official forum with same question https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/G3-17-3779-Ubuntu-18-04-LTS/td-p/6106352

Ubuntu hardware compatibility https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=g3&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&level=Any&vendors=Dell